# Colormap index off by one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib's `ListedColorMap`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as clr

cmap = clr.ListedColormap(['#000000', '#ee82ee', '#4b0082', '#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ffa500', '#ff0000', '#00ffff', '#ffc0cb'], name='test-cmap')
```

[image: plotted cmap]

10 colors with indexing:

- 0 black
- 1 violet
- 2 indigo
- 3 blue
- 4 green
- 5 yellow
- 6 orange
- 7 red
- 8 cyan
- 9 pink

When I populate NumPy array of shape of (10, 1) corresponding to indexes of the colormap, it is off by one if I do not include index 9:

```
ar = np.zeros((10, 1))

ar[0, 0] = 2
ar[1, 0] = 0
ar[2, 0] = 0
ar[3, 0] = 2
ar[4, 0] = 0
ar[5, 0] = 5
ar[6, 0] = 0
ar[7, 0] = 0
ar[8, 0] = 0
ar[9, 0] = 3

plt.imsave('{}/apus.png'.format(outputDir), ar, cmap=cmap)
```

I should see colors found at indexes 0, 2, 3, 5. Indexes relate to colors black, indigo, blue and yellow. Instead saved image has black, green, pink and orange:

[image: incorrect image]

If I add a 9 (pink by index, last index in colormap), image relates correctly to colormap:

```
ar = np.zeros((10, 1))
ar[0, 0] = 2
ar[1, 0] = 9 # Pink added
ar[2, 0] = 0
ar[3, 0] = 2
ar[4, 0] = 0
ar[5, 0] = 5
ar[6, 0] = 0
ar[7, 0] = 0
ar[8, 0] = 0
ar[9, 0] = 3

plt.imsave('{}/apus.png'.format(outputDir), ar, cmap=cmap)
```

[image: correct image]

I can put the 9 value at any index and image is saved with the right color mapping. What is going on here?

Comment: Why do you expect the colors to be used consecutively? If you use the default colormap, [`'viridis'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUc8N.png), you will see the same behavior. [The outer two colors and the two middle colors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z2Sv.png)

Comment: Maybe that is my misunderstanding.  I would expect my 10 color colormap to me mapped by the order they are defined in a simple int32 based data array.  I'm going to try the viridis colormap to see if I grok what you are saying

Comment: I think the color cycler attempts to set the colors at the extremes. If all the numbers are the same, regardless of the number, the color will be the first color in the colormap

Comment: That seems odd to me.  I'm not trying to use the colors consecutively if I understand you correctly.  Basically I have image data that has a shape of 512x512 where each element in that array contains values between 0 and 9 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) where each value should map to a color.  My understanding is that the cmap I created above having those 10 hex values in the order of the list would map correctly

Comment: 0 to 9 are not valid rgb(a) values. `cmap`: _A Colormap instance or registered colormap name. The colormap maps scalar data to colors. It is ignored for RGB(A) data._

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you so much for commenting and helping me understand a bit more about colormaps.  I think I have figured it out my problem and I'm seeing correct behavior now with this colormap. ```colors = ['#000000', '#ee82ee', '#4b0082', '#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ffa500', '#ff0000', '#00ffff', '#ffc0cb']
cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney can you move your first comment as the answer so I can reward this question to you?

Comment: Your colormap is arranged from 0 to 1 so the values will be determined by dividing the value by the max value in list thus normalizing between 0 and 1. This is why 9 at any position works and why removing 9 offsets the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how color mapping works. Individual values are not mapped to colors. Instead, the plotter attempts to map the entire color range across all of your data. In your first example, the smallest value in the array is zero, so that is mapped to lowest end of your color range (black). The largest value is 5, so that is mapped to the high end of the color range (pink). All other values are assigned to colors that are interpolated between 0 and 5. Your color range is "stretched" between the highest and lowest values in the array.